# How to calculate the throughput in the "throughput" example of INET?

Tags: omnet++

I am considering the idea of using Inet/omnet++ to evaluate a routing algorithm we are working on. Since I am using the tool for the first time, I was executing some examples and reading the source code.
Then I found an example, which is shipped with inet, /inet/examples/wireless/throughput.

The problem is that I don't get the same values.

In the README file one can read:

```
"Throughput is measured by the "sink" submodule of the AP. It is recorded
into the output scalar file, but can also be inspected during runtime.

The Excel sheet includes throughput measured by the simulation, and compares
it to the theoretical maximum which is roughly 5.12 Mbps (at 11 Mbps bitrate
and 1000-byte packets). The theoretical value and the simulation output
are very close, the difference being less than 1 kbps."
```

The same value is presented in Timing.xls

However, I obtain a different value when I execute the simulation: 846266 bit/sec

Do I need to perform some additional calculation to obtain the final value of throughput?

Is that a bug?

Is the value no longer valid due to some modification in INET?

Answer (score 0):

The default value of bitrate for `throughput` example is 1 Mbps. So the value you obtained is correct. 
To change the bitrate edit this line in `omnetpp.ini` in `throughput` directory: 
 
`**.wlan*.bitrate = 1Mbps`

Comment: You are right, I obtain a closer value when I use a bitrare of 11Mbps. However, it is not close enough to the theoretical value presented in the README file, nor to the measured value mentioned there. The value I obtain is 4828849 bit/sec. I tried adding `**.mac.slotTime = 20us` but it doesn't impact the throughput. Any idea?